# Sending a post request with AFNNetworking returning an error:unacceptable content-type: text/html

Tags: json, afnetworking-2, http-post

Im trying now for 2 days to make a post request to my API (which i made with Laravel) with AFNNetworking but somehow i'm getting the following error:

> (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)

my php code in laravel looks likes this:

```
Route::post('api/v1/users/{username}', function($username){


   return Response::json(array(
        'response'=>'succes',
        'message'=>'User succesfully created'
    ));
});
```

when i test this code with postman for example it works fine, but when i'm sending a POST request with AFNNetworking it doesn't work and i seriously searched and try everything i could before i came here for help.

My Objective C code looks like below:

```
+(void)logInWithUsernameInBackground:(NSString *)username
                            password:(NSString *)password
                               block:(FBUserResultBlock)loginWithBlock {




    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];



    NSString *url = @"http://192.168.0.106/testLaravel/api/v1/users/";
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":username};


    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",error);

    }];


}
```

Strange thing is when i remove the line:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

i get the error:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x1780f4f80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170248cd0 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html".

i seriously don't get what im doing wrong. If there is someone that can help me here out i would really appreciate it.

Tnx

Comment: Is there no one that can help me out with this one?

Comment: This topic can be close i already solved the problem. The problem was on the server side.

Comment: Im getting the same error.  What was your server error?

Comment: @marciokoko You probably sending an json but on your server side level you don't accepting json content type. If u want to achieve that you shoud set content type in the top of your file.